# Running unit tests on xamarin ios "NOT" in parallel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nunit

I have a unit test project on my xamarin.ios application. is there any way to force the unit tests to run in sequence and not parallel.

**Please**, I don't need any advice such as "You should write your unit tests in an independent way." or something like that. 
All I need is, "Is it possible to run the tests **NOT** in parallel using nUnitlite."

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExpenseTests
{
    string _dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "expensemanager.db3");

    public void DbSetup()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_dbPath))
            File.Delete(_dbPath);

        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformIOS(), _dbPath);
        db.CreateTable<Category>();
        db.CreateTable<Expense>();

        var category = new Category()
        {
            Name = "category",
            Plan = 20
        };
        category.Upsert();
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void Create_NegativeValue()
    {
        DbSetup();
        var expense = new Expense()
        {
            CategoryId = _categoryId,
            Description = string.Empty,
            Value = -10
        };
        expense.Upsert();
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void Create_LongDescription()
    {
        DbSetup();
        string description = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < 201; i++)
        {
            description += i;
        }
        var expense = new Expense()
        {
            CategoryId = _categoryId,
            Description = description,
            Value = 10
        };
        expense.Upsert();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us one file of your tests please (an entire class)? Also, are you using this attribute - https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute ?

Comment: @mjwills I've updated the question with the class.

Comment: What library are you building your tests against? Unless you've custom implemented ExpectedExceptionAttribute, you appear to be using an NUnit 2.x version. NUnit 2 didn't have any parallilization, apart from what was implemented by external projects.

Comment: Are you using MonoTouch.NUnitLite - as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/)? Or [Xamarin.UiTest](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/installing-nunit-using-nuget/)?

Comment: this is what I'm using https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/NUnit/